# node socket client set connection flags

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I'm using `net.Socket` in node.js to communicate with my DVR cameras server. When connecting to the server I need to specify th ECN and CWR flags, but I can't seem to find any method to do so.
Is it possible to setup the connection flags in node or I must create a C extension that do so?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find any reference to setting those flags within node.js either.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only set those system wide (at least on Windows, not sure about linux). On windows, use "netsh interface tcp set global ecncapability=enabled"

Comment: @C.Gonzalez I noticed that I need these flags when listening to a current app that connects to my DVR cameras and does put them. When it does, the right response come out (I'm sending the exact same packets).